# How to write a code with OMPL -Part1-

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, global-planner, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I might put a similar question on this web. As writing a subject, I want to understand how to write a code with OMPL to move a turtlebot. Now, I'm writing the code. I think global_planner with OMPL needs next steps.

1.isStateValid()
<s>isStateValid() is a function to check if a position putting a sampler on a map  is free space.</s>
isStateValid() is a function to store information like free space and obstacle region.

2.makePlan()
makePlan() includes `ob::PlannerPtr planner( og::RRT(ss.getSpaceInformation()))`,  `setStateValidityChecker()` and so on.

On this article the contents I want to ask is following.
`isStateValid` has to receive state of OMPL format instead of costmap, so my code is wrong.
As I explain above, costmap has many information about an obstacle. So I think that I should use a costmap.
How should I edit this code? or Could anyone tell me more information if I'm not correct?

```
   bool isStateValid(costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
   costmap_ros_ = costmap_ros;
   costmap_ = costmap_ros_->getCostmap();
    
   if(costmap_ > 253)
        return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Error message

```
/home/ken/catkin_ws/src/navigation/ompl_planner_rrt/src/ompl_planner_rrt.cpp: In function ‘bool ompl_planner_rrt::isStateValid(costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS*)’:
/home/ken/catkin_ws/src/navigation/ompl_planner_rrt/src/ompl_planner_rrt.cpp:62:3: error: ‘costmap_ros_’ was not declared in this scope
```

I edited ompl_planner_rrt.h like a following.

```
namespace ompl_planner_rrt{
    class OMPLPlannerRRT : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner {
       public:    
           OMPLPlannerRRT();
           OMPLPlannerRRT(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);

           void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);

           bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start,
                  const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal, 
                  std::vector& plan);
           ~OMPLPlannerRRT();
       private:
           double footprintCost(double x_i, double y_i, double theta_i);
           bool isStateValid(const ompl::base::State *state);
           bool interpolatePathPose2D(std::vector& path);
           void publishPlan(std::vector path);
           void OMPLStateSE2ToROSPose2D(const ompl::base::State* ompl_state, geometry_msgs::Pose2D& pose2D);
           void OMPLScopedStateSE2ToROSPose2D(const ompl::base::ScopedState scoped_state, geometry_msgs::Pose2D& pose2D);
           void ROSPose2DToOMPLScopedStateSE2(ompl::base::ScopedState& scoped_state, const geometry_msgs::Pose2D pose2D);  
           void PoseToPose2D(const geometry_msgs::Pose pose, geometry_msgs::Pose2D& pose2D);
           void Pose2DToPose(geometry_msgs::Pose& pose, const geometry_msgs::Pose2D pose2D);
    };
};
```

```
Linking CXX shared library /home/ken/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libompl_planner_rrt.so
[100%] Built target ompl_planner_rrt
```

But, I have no confidence if my program works normally.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173229/how-to-write-a-code-with-ompl--part1-/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-10**:
Anyone is about to tell me to study C++.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-06-10**:
Have you declared "costmap_ros_" variable? I guess that variable is a class variable.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-10**:
Thanks @alfa_80, I don't understand costmap_2d. I know that It consists of Layered costmap. But I don't know how to take out cost from costmap. I'm checking it.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-10**:
I quote a sample code GeomPlanningSE2_PRM.cpp on the web( http://robotics.naist.jp/edu/text/?Robotics%2FOMPL#OMPLProgramming ). isStateValid in this cpp just sets free space and obstacle region. That means this doesn't have a function to check if free space is.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-10**:
I guess that isStateValid() is necessary to store information of costmap. I need to know the way to transfer from costmap to statespace of OMPL format.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-15**:
I deleted my answer, because anyone denied my answer. I know the reason that I intend to use a code with a bug. I want to know an essential answer to move a turtlebot with OMPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your reference to costmap_ros_ variable has not been declared. The format suggests it's a member variable, so if you're moving it to a different class that may be a problem.

---

Originally posted by [osrf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18834/osrf/) with karma: 26 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-10**:
Thanks @osrf, I replaced isStateValid( ) to ompl_planner_rrt::OMPLPlannerRRT::isStateValid( ). So, error message has gone out.